# How portlet producers initiate refresh/push to consumers on demand (I'm using Jdeveloper 11.1.1.6 ADF-JSF)

Tags: weblogic, portlet, oracle-adf, portal, webcenter

I am new to the oracle Webcenter portlets:

My requirement is my Portlet Producer serves N number of consumers . I do need to refresh or push content to those consumers whenever changes occur at my producer .

My questions are :

1. How to keep track of all active consumers for my portlet-producer ? what technique to use ?
2. How producer could communicate with consumer and refresh or push the content?

I was able to refresh the consumer(Consumer side request initiated) by setting time interval in javascript(Jquery) and making ajax request to the producer. But i do like to know how can the refresh or push initiated from my producer?

I'am a beginner in Oracle webcenter so guide me regarding this in detail.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Active Data Service for server side push using ADF components, you can find the docs [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E15523_01/web.1111/b31974/adv_ads.htm).

For your first question you could keep track of the user's sessions by using some counter in the application scope.